# What's wrong with the "new" keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I know that this might sound like a stupid question, but why do I get an error which says something like "

> cannot convert Object* to Object

" when I try to instantiate a new Object by using the statement "

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

"?

Am I to understand that the "**new**" keyword is reserved for pointers?  Or is it something else?

Comment: There's nothing from with `new`. Only with your understanding of it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. C++ just has different semantics and you have to forget what you assumed you knew. Understanding C++ requires understanding where objects are stored (heap or stack). Then you understand why `new` necessarily returns a pointer.

Comment: C++ is neither Java nor C#; there are differences, and you have identified one.

Comment: Why does the title say C++, your question have C++, yet you tagged it C?

Comment: In any case, if you want to learn C++, you need to get a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @andand, +1 totally agree. To the poster please read up on pointers and references in C++.

Comment: Surprised to see 4 up votes for this question.

Comment: @delnan.  Obviously, but what I was asking was why did the compiler react the way it did with new?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
Object* obj = new Object();
```

`new` always return pointer to object.

if you write just `Object obj` it means that `obj` will hold the object itself. If it is declared this way inside function then memory will be allocated on stack and will be wiped once you leave that function. `new` allocates memory on heap, so the pointer can be returned from function. Note that pointer can also point to local (stack) variable also.

Comment: @Andrey You're lucky. [There's bored people around here, today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716629/c-error-returning-a-char-array/4716656#4716656). You only got one downvote. ;-)

Comment: @Andrey: Wasn't me but if it were I'd imagine it were the `Object* ob...` vs `Object *ob...` notation I admit I was thinking about it...;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner it is matter of taste, i don't downvote if i don't like the notation. Personally i prefer `Object* ob` because it looks as a type. yeah i know that `Object* ob1, ob2` should be `Object *ob1, *ob2`.

Comment: @goreSplatter i don't care about downvote, just want to know what is wrong.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: that's pretty idiomatic for C++ (as an old C fart the `T* p` convention annoys me, but the more C++ I do the more I understand why it became the convention).  For me, that wouldn't be sufficient reason for a downvote.

Comment: @John: You're right, it's probably not worth a downvote (though I've seen downvotes for even less than this), but that's the only thing I can see in there that might provoke it, and I mentioned it because I was thinking it, and maybe I wasn't the only one?

Comment: @Andrey: Maybe someone thought that 20 upvotes was too many for such an obvious answer.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Punitive downvoting? When the guy already has 19.4k rep? Not sure there's much point in that...

Comment: Perhaps it was the use of stack and heap. It is only storage duration which is guaranteed by the C++ standard, things can be stored wherever the compiler wants as long as the semantics don't change.

Answer (score 8):

Since `new` returns a pointer, you ought to use

```
Object *obj = new Object();
```

Comment: I prefer Object * obj myself.

Comment: @Thomas: How about `Object*obj`? ;-)

Comment: @Fred: Ha, too easy to overlook the operator . . .

Answer (score 6):

Exactly. New creates an object on the heap, and *returns a pointer to it*.

Answer (score 6):

the new operator makes a pointer to a object

there for `Object *obj = new Object()` should work.

but just Object obj() constructs the object just fine but in stack space

Comment: `Object obj()` can be global variable and will be not on stack

Comment: `Object obj();` declares a function named `obj` that takes no parameters and returns an `Object`.

Answer (score 6):

Object obj;

is all you need. It creates the object obj.

Comment: Probably that's what he needs; but we can't take it for granted.

Answer (score 1):

I would have simply left a comment, but apparently I need a certain rep to do so.

In Java, variables used to store Objects are implicitly pointers to the Object. So `new` works the same way in C++ as Java, but you're not made aware of it in Java. I am going to guess that's the reason for your confusion.